# Wordpress bbpress -- can't display sidebar in custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar, bbpress

I've developed a custom theme in Wordpress and am trying to add bbPress forums.

I have numerous custom sidebars with my theme, and the default sidebar is displaying on the forums page. So I:

-- Registered a new sidebar in my theme's functions.php file

-- Created a new sidebar php file with the sidebar's i.d.

-- Created a new template for my forum page that calls the new sidebar

– Selected that template from the community page per the WP interface

– Moved the bbPress widgets over into my newly created sidebar

But the page still displays the default sidebar.  It seems my bbPress forums page may not be a proper WP page at all and so it makes no difference if I give it a custom page template.  Does anyone know how to create a custom page in bbPress?

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself by adding this code at the bottom of my page template:

```
if (is_bbpress()) {
    get_sidebar(forum);
    } ?>
```

So it looks like the bbpress forum page will ONLY default to the page template, and that's where you need to call a custom sidebar.

cheers, Cheryl